# Error while parsing out few fields from dictionary to CSV

Tags: python, csv, parsing, pandas, dictionary

```
b

{u'message': {u'method': u'XXXX',
  u'params': {u'documentURL': u'xxxx',
     u'A': u'yyyy',
     u'initialPriority': u'Medium',
    u'method': u'GET',
    u'mixedContentType': u'none',
    u'url': u'xxxx'},
   u'date': u'qqqq',
   u'time': u'wwww',
   u'type': u'Other',
   u'wallTime': u'uuuu'},
 u'webview': u'0'}
```

I am trying to parse out only few fields from a very big dictionary into a csv. The following is what I have tried,

```
result = []
for i, val in enumerate(b):
    output['a']= b[i]['message']['params']['A']
    output['date'] = b[i]['message']['date']
    output['time'] = b[i]['message']['time']
    output['passed'] = b[i]['message']['action']['output']['passed']
    result.append(output)

x = pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(result))
x.to_csv('output.csv',  encoding='utf-8')
```

The problem here is the dictionary is not properly structured and some time variable like `passed (b[i]['message']['action']['output']['passed'])` is not present and therefore there is a error coming up because of this. How do to make this code to append only when value is present and if value is not present make it NULL?

i want to parse out only when the field is present and if it is not present, want to have it as NULL. Can anybody help me in doing this?

Also is there a more efficient way to do this parsing?

Comment: What is b?  Please post the entire relevant code

Comment: oh sorry. b is like a dictionary. It was very big to post. That is why I didn't keep it here. I can edit it if you want.

Comment: Can you post a part of it, or post a link to entire dictionary so we know how it looks like and what is the structure?

Comment: You will need an if condition for every field that may or may not be present, to check if it is present and then append either they value or NULL based on the condition.

Comment: Is b a dictionary or a list of dictionaries ?

Comment: @Wajahat list of dictionaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is assuming that 'message' is always present, but others may or may not:

```
result = []
for k in b:
    msg=b[k]['message'] # if b is a dictionary of dictionaries
    msg=k['message'] # if b is a list of dictionaries
    if 'params' in msg:
        if 'A' in msg['params']:
            output['a']=msg['params']['A']
        else:
            output['a']="NULL"
    else:
        output['a']="NULL"
    if 'date' in msg:
        output['date']=msg['date']
    else:
        output['date']="NULL"
    if 'time' in msg:
        output['time']=msg['time']
    else:
        output['time']="NULL"
    if 'action' in msg:
        if 'output' in msg['action']:
            if 'passed' in msg['actions']['output']:
                output['passed']=msg['actions']['output']['passed']
            else:
                output['passed']="NULL"
        else:
            output['passed']="NULL"
    else:
        output['passed']="NULL"
    result.append(output)

x = pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(result))
x.to_csv('output.csv',  encoding='utf-8')
```

This approach does not scale, but will work if you only have to get few fields out of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get()` instead of `[]`, since it returns `None` if key is not present in the dictionary.

Comment: [] will also return None if key is not present in dictionary.

Comment: `[]` will give a `KeyError` if key is not present. It will return `None` only if the key is present but the value is `None`.

Comment: Hmm okay yeah. But just using get will pose the same problem and "NoneType has no attribute" exception will be thrown.

Comment: Depends on whether only the final key is missing or intermediate keys are missing too. If former, this should work. If latter, OP needs to add null checks for every step.